# How Does This Argument Go Wrong?

Tags: abstract-algebra, fake-proofs

Consider a binary operation & defined by (a&b)=(a-(b+(a*b))) on the integers, with "a" and "b" as integers.  One might argue as follows:

By closure (a*b) equals an integer, which we'll call k.  Thus, (a-(b+(a*b)))=(a-(b+k).  By closure (a+k) equals an integer, which we'll call j.  Thus, (a-(b+(a*b)))=(a-(b+k)=(a-j).  Since (a-j) means the same thing as (a+i) where i indicates the inverse of j we can write:
(a-(b+(a*b)))=(a+i).  Thus, (a-(b+(a*b))) or (a&b) consists of an addition of two integers.  Addition associates on the integers, meaning that for all x, y, z (x+(y+z))=((x+y)+z).  Therefore, & associates on the integers also.

This argument is not valid, since if a=0, b=1, we have

(0&(0&1))=(0&-1)=1 and

((0&0)&1)=(0&1)=(-1).

How does the above argument fail?

Comment: The operation "$-$" consists of adding two integers ($a-b = a + (-b)$), but it isn't associative. The integers you're adding when computing $a\&b$ are not $a$ and $b$ themselves, so there is no reason to think that associativity would carry over.

Comment: The sentence "Therefore, & associates on the integers also" does not follow from anything you said earlier.

Comment: The flaw is thinking that the $i$ you obtained by examining $a\& b$ depends on $a$ and $b$ in an _associative_ way.

Comment: Remark that the operation becomes associative if you replace the subtraction by addition, yielding $\rm\: a*b = a+b+ab.\:$ Then it amounts to labeling each element by its successor, i.e. [transporting](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/316836/prove-that-this-ring-is-an-integral-domain-based-on-newly-defined-binary-operati#comment686079_316857) the [ring structure](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/316836/prove-that-this-ring-is-an-integral-domain-based-on-newly-defined-binary-operati#comment686050_316861) along the bijection $\rm\: x\mapsto x+1.\ \ $

Answer (score 3):

The operation $x \star y = x + \sin y$ consists of the addition of real numbers, namely $x$ and $\sin y$, but isn't associative. It has to be the addition *of the arguments of the binary operation* in order for associativity to be inherited.

You should check associativity, or lack thereof, by direct calculation.

Comment: It is not true that it *has* to be addition to be associative. For example $\rm\: x \star y = x + f(y)\:$ is associative for any idempotent linear $\rm\:f,\:$ e.g. $\rm\:f(y) = ey,\:$ for $\rm\:e\:$ idempotent, e.g. $\rm\ x + 5y\ (mod\ 10).\ \ $