# Proving the associativity of a monoid with $a \circ b = a+b-ab$

Tags: proof-writing, algebraic-groups

For university, it was my excercise to proof the associativity of the monoid $$H=(\mathbb{Q},\circ)\text{ with } a \circ b := a+b-ab\quad(a,b \in \mathbb{Q})$$

The excercise instructor gave us the following solution:
$$ a \circ(b \circ c) = (a \circ b) \circ c $$
Hence
$$ (a+b-ab) \circ c = a+c-ac \quad+\quad b+c-bc \quad +\quad-ab-c+abc$$
He also did it for $a\circ(b+c-bc)$ and pointed out that both equations have the same summands. That was the proof for the assoiciativity and I do understand this so far.

What I do not understand is how he determined the third part with $ -ab-c+abc$.

If I rewrite the operation to $\alpha \circ \beta = \alpha + \beta - \alpha\beta$ for not mixing up the variables later, I get:

$\alpha = -ab \\
\beta = c$

And hence in my mind it is not $-ab-c+abc$ but $-ab+c +abc$. But when I keep on calculating with $+c$ instead of $-c$, my proof fails. So why has it to be $-c$?

Comment: It seems you have some typos on line 6. Since $(a \circ b) \circ c = (a+b-ab)\circ c = a+b-ab + c - (a+b-ab)c$.

Comment: Well, I checked it again and in line 6 is character by character the solution he gave us. Is line 6 wrong? I thought this was correct since I could follow his argumentation (without why I had to use $-c$ instead of $+c$)

Comment: As i understood the definition of $\circ$, in order to find $(a+b-ab) \circ c$ we need: the first component ($a+b-ab$) plus the second ($c$) and minus the product of the first ($a+b-ab$) and the second ($c$).

Comment: Well I think you are right. This makes a lot more sense. I wonder what my excercise instructor did. I simply think it's completely wrong?

Comment: I hope that there was some noise introduced between what your instructor wrote and what is written above. 
A first and major error is "$a\circ (b\circ c)=(a\circ b)\circ c)$. Hence $\dots$". We want to **prove** that for all $a,b,c$ we have $a\circ (b\circ c)=(a\circ b)\circ c)$. So we cannot *start* by asserting that the equality holds, and derive conclusions from that. For the proof, just calculate, substituting correctly.

Comment: Note that if f(x) = 1-x, then your x * y is nothing but f ^{-1}(f(x)f(y)), where f(x)f(y) is usual multiplication.

Comment: See also [this question.](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/316836/242)

Comment: @AndréNicolas Sorry, this was my fault. He stated that we have to proof $ a \circ (b \circ c) = (a \circ b) \circ c$ for associativity. He didn't mentioned it as a fact.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For every $a,b,c\in \mathbb{Q}$ we have
\begin{eqnarray}
a\circ(b\circ c)&=&a\circ\underbrace{(b+c-bc)}_{d}=a+d-ad=a+(b+c-bc)-a(b+c-bc)\\
&=&a+b+c-bc-ab-ac+abc=a+b-ab+c-ac-bc+abc\\
&=&\underbrace{(a+b-ab)}_{e}+c-\underbrace{(a+b-ab)}_{e}c=e+c-ec=e\circ c\\
&=&(a\circ b)\circ c.
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: It's a great idea to substitute it this way. I wonder why we didn't learned it that way. That's a solution I understand, thank you for that!

Answer (score 2):

It may be easier if you look at the bijective map
$$
f\colon \mathbb{Q}\to \mathbb{Q},\quad f(a)=1-a.
$$
You can notice that
$$f(a\circ b)=1-a\circ b=1-a-b+ab=(1-a)(1-b)=f(a)\cdot f(b).$$
Let's call “property H” the equality
$$
f(a\circ b)=f(a)\cdot f(b)
$$
that holds for all $a,b\in \mathbb{Q}$.

Thus $f$ is an isomorphism between $(\mathbb{Q},\circ)$ and $(\mathbb{Q},\cdot)$. Since one operation is associative, also the other one is.

To see why, consider
\begin{align}
f((a\circ b)\circ c)&=f(a\circ b))\cdot f(c) &&\text{by property H} \\[2ex]
&=(f(a)\cdot f(b))\cdot f(c) &&\text{by property H} \\[2ex]
&=f(a)\cdot (f(b)\cdot f(c)) &&\text{associativity of multiplication} \\[2ex]
&=f(a)\cdot f(b\circ c) &&\text{by property H} \\[2ex]
&=f(a\circ(b\circ c)) &&\text{by property H}
\end{align}
Since $f$ is injective, we conclude that $(a\circ b)\circ c=a\circ(b\circ c)$.

This is a general fact; if $X$ and $Y$ are endowed with two operations, say $(X,\circ)$ and $(Y,*)$ and $f\colon X\to Y$ is a bijective map with the property that
$$
f(a\circ b)=f(a)*f(b)
$$
for all $a,b\in X$, then one operation is associative if and only if the other one is and the proof is just the same as before. We are basically transferring one operation to the other set, so any “algebraic property” holding for one operation holds true also for the other one. This is what's called an *isomorphism* between algebraic structures.

Comment: **Remark** that related circle compositions [plays an important conceptual role](http://books.google.com/books?id=KlMDjaJxZAkC&pg=PA8) in the radical theory of rings ([quasi-refular elements,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasiregular_element) etc).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Actually, I can follow your steps you've posted. Unfortunately I do not get the intention behind it and do not understand this proof. I think I have too less background-knowledge about it :(

Comment: @Drudge I'll expand my answer.